# How to convert String into if expression?

Tags: java, stack, queue

Is there any way in JAVA to convert a String directly to an expression?

```
String s="(accountName==TESTDATA1) && (CONTAINER==bank) ||(includeInNetWorth==true)";
if(s==true){
  //I want to do something
}
```

Comment: `Boolean.parseBoolean`?

Comment: @Eugene `parseBoolean` returns true only if you pass the string `true` (ignoring case). The OP wants to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @user7 yup.. I understood that, bad sugestion

Comment: No. Java does not provide such functionality. And you can't get local variable from their names at runtime.

Comment: @user7 though the linked answer is good, I think the OP needs those variables `accountName`, `CONTAINER` etc. from some context, not sure this would be possible

Comment: I have gone through this link but could not find how this solution will suffice my requirement. Could u pls help in framing the code?

Comment: @Eugene the accepted answer on the linked question shows how to pass values into the script engine (`engine.eval("value = 10");`). Should be possible in this example, too

Comment: accountName,Container etc are coming to from the json file. I just want that String expression to return somehow true/false.

Comment: @MalteHartwig I understand that, I am just saying if the context is big, I dont think this is going to be by any means easy

Comment: "I just want" is not a magic sentence to make a great solution appear, you'll need some work to achieve this.

Comment: @rahulkumar have you tried copying the code from the answer in the linked question and replace the conditions with yours and the `"value = 10"` by something like `"\"TESTDATA1\" = " + myJson.get("accountName")`? You need to show us some code for us to help. It would also show us why you need to evaluate the expression as a String instead of plain Java.

Comment: If those variables are class fields you may achieve it with reflection. But if they are local variables I believe there's no way to do this. btw, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I dont think there is way to convert String to expression, however if someone can help me in splitting that string based on && and || both such that after splitting each expression can be treated as separate comparision.

Comment: I guess i have got the solution how to break it. below is my code.                                                                              String [] s1 = s.split("\\||&&");
  for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
   System.out.println(s1[i]);